# Tobit model with flexible censoring point in R

Tags: censoring, tobit-regression

I am currently writing my MSc thesis and I am using a Tobit model.

My data consists of fleet and sales data. The censored dependent variable is quantity and this quantity is higher than the fleet number. However, this fleet number differs for every line.

I found that I could use the crch package in R and use the fleet numbers as a right censoring point. Or I think I can use that.

But I am wondering, is there also another option to estimate the regression with a changing number as censoring point?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have that each sample unit in your dataset has a different censoring point. You can easily do that using the `survreg()` function from the [**survival**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) package in R. Using the `Surv()` function you can define the type of censoring you have in the `formula` argument of `survreg()`, and with the `dist` argument you can define the distribution of your outcome, e.g., `"gaussian"`.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify how I should use surv in the survreg formula?

Comment: Check this example from the manual of the survival package: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/tobin.html